# Delimit data coming from socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking

In my Java application there is a Socket open and data is being read from its InputStream.

In optimal conditions each packet that comes in results in a call to read() returning its application layer data. This is what I am trying to get - one 'message' per **packet**.

However, it is possible that data gets buffered in the socket based on what getReceiveBufferSize() returns. If this happens and the stream is read from, there may be data from multiple packets sitting there.

Is there another method to get data from individual packets, or does that violate layers of abstraction?
Alternatively, is it possible to set some sort of delimiter for when data gets appended to the buffer? Or is that something at the platform level that cannot be done?

Here is some example code to demonstrate what I am doing:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Belnets {


public Belnets() {
    try{
        Socket s = new Socket("address", 23);
        System.out.println("platform will buffer this much: "+s.getReceiveBufferSize());
        InputStream sin = s.getInputStream();
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int c;
        while(true){
            c = sin.read(data);
            for(int i=0; i<c; i++){
                System.out.print((char)data[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("=END OF READ=");

            //if you dont do this, read() seems to return once for each packet as this loop 
            //appears to be running fast enough to keep up with the rate of data that comes in.
            //otherwise data gets buffered and you get multiple packets worth of data before seeing
            //=END OF READ=
            Thread.sleep(1000);     

        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}   



public static void main(String args[]){
    new Belnets();
}

}
```

Comment: `while(true)` should be `while(c != -1)`

Comment: Can you change how the data is sent?  If yes, you can add an end-of-message dlimiter to the end of the sent message, which you could look for when receiving the data (make sure you select a delimiter that cannot be part of a message normally)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java API doesn't provide any way to read TCP packets. It's stream-based, and you have absolutely no way to read one packet at a time.

If you want to send and receive multiple messages, you need to implement an application-level protocol, which might use a specific delimiter between messages, or send the length of a message followed by the message body itself, for example.

Answer (score 2):

> In optimal conditions each packet that comes in results in a call to read() returning its application layer data.

No. This isn't 'optimal conditions', this is sheer luck. There is nothing in Java or the underlying BSD Sockets API or the TCP RFCs that gives any right to rely on that behaviour. TCP is a streaming protocol, period, and the APIs are byte-stream APIs, also period.

If you want application messages or packets you have to implement them yourself, via:

1. Prefixing a length word to each message.
2. Use a higher-level protocol such as Object Serialization, XDR, etc.
3. Use a self-describing protocol such as XML, JSON, etc.

In each case you must read in a loop at the receiver until you have the entire message.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop needs to be altered:

```
while (true) {
    c = sin.read(data);
    if (c < 0)
        break;    // quit if there's nothing else to read.
    for(int i=0; i<c; i++){
        System.out.print((char)data[i]);
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible or a good idea to try to read TCP packets.  TCP is stream-based which  means there's no guarantee everything will be sent/received all at once.  You might consider using UDP (which is less reliable but everything does get sent at once), or coming up with your own delimiting scheme.  (A popular one is to send the length of your "packet" followed by the actual packet itself.)